# TypeError: Cannot read property 'userId' - sendbird

Tags: javascript, sendbird

i am trying to create a channel between 2 sendbird users using group channel. So far my implementation is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function chatInit(){
        var sb = new SendBird({
            appId: 'my app id'
         });

    sb.connect('test user','access token of user', function(user, error) {
    console.log(error);

    }); 
    var userIds = ['another user'];
    var name ="name of channel";
    sb.GroupChannel.createChannelWithUserIds(userIds, true, name ,'', '', function(channel, error) {
             if (error) {
        console.error(error);
    return;
}

});

}
</script>
```

and i get following error on console

```
SendBird.min.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'userId' of null
at Function.GroupChannel.createChannelWithUserIds
```

am i missing something, please guide me through the process. 
any and all help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you get that error response is because the connect has not run to completion as at the time the code

```
sb.GroupChannel.createChannelWithUserIds()
```

is run.

You need to add that add that block of code inside the callback function of sb.connect() like so:

```
function chatInit(){
    var sb = new SendBird({
        appId: 'my app id'
     });

     var userIds = ['another user'];

     sb.connect('test user','access token of user', function(user, error) {
         console.log(error);

         if(user){
              var name ="name of channel";
              sb.GroupChannel.createChannelWithUserIds(userIds, true, name ,'', '', function(channel, error) {
                  if (error) {
                       console.error(error);
                       return;
                  }
              }); 
         }
     }
}
```